# VBA Copy Gives me a 400 Error

Tags: excel, vba

I had this working perfectly fine, and then for a reason unknown to me it now produces a 400 error:

```
Set ws = Sheets("Overview")

         LastCol = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
            After:=ws.Range("A1"), _
            LookAt:=xlPart, _
            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
            MatchCase:=False).Column

           ws.Columns(LastCol).Copy ws.Columns(LastCol + 1)
```

The copy part works fine, but where it seems to fail is copying it to the new column and I cannot figure out why

Comment: How do you know the copy part works and the paste dont?  Is it finding the LastCol value correctly?  Can you write the complete description of the error message.

Comment: Its just a 400 error.  I've think i've found my problem.  I appear to have a memory leak in excel caused by one of my vba statements :(

Comment: You should probably check the result of the `Find` statement because it might be empty: see [Siddarth Rout blog post about find](http://siddharthrout.wordpress.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest this rather than copying anyway. There is no need to involve the clipboard here:

```
       ws.Columns(LastCol + 1).value = ws.Columns(LastCol).Value
```

Comment: I would still set the formatting like this where possible. If you use the clipboard in code your function has effects outside of the scope of excel. It could mess up your copying and pasting in other applications while that VBA runs in the background.